# remove comma (%2C), apostrophe (%27), colon (%3A) from url

Tags: .htaccess

How to remove comma (%2C), apostrophe (%27), colon (%3A) from title of the url using htaccess
my url is
https://xklsv.me/Funding-Friday%3A-Jelly2/fred/August-7th-2020

desired url
https://xklsv.me/Funding-Friday:-Jelly2/fred/August-7th-2020

https://xklsv.me/Tactics%2C-Political-Tactics/BigRedCar/August-9th-2020

desired url
https://xklsv.me/Tactics,-Political-Tactics/BigRedCar/August-9th-2020

this is my code what i have tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^title=([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+)$
RewriteRule ^viewblog1\.php$ /%1/%2/%4? [R=301]
RewriteRule ^viewblog1/([\w+%]{2,50})$ /viewblog1.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ viewblog1.php?title=$1&user=$2&date=$3
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+)$ viewblog1.php?title=$1/$2/$1/$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*):(.*)$ /viewblog1.php?title=$1/$2/$1/$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*),(.*)$ /viewblog1.php?title=$1/$2/$1/$3 [L]
```

Comment: What has your research turned up so far, what did you try? Please go read [ask]. (We are not here for people to simply “outsource” this part of their job to us all day long.)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=htaccess+rewrite+replace+character+site:stackoverflow.com could be a start.

Comment: Also post what are desired URLs for your source URLs.

Comment: @anubhava sir i have updated my question please check

Comment: Thanks but how are you getting these hex characters in your URL?

Comment: sir i'm getting this because of  urlencode($title) and i will have to use this because hyperlink is not clickable if colon : is present in the url after using urlencode($title) i'm able to click on the link but after clicking on the link i'm getting %3A in place of : colon

Answer (score 0):

You may use these 3 redirect rules at top of your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(\S*?)%3A(\S*)
RewriteRule . /%1:%2 [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(\S*?)%2C(\S*)
RewriteRule . /%1,%2 [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(\S*?)%27(\S*)
RewriteRule . /%1'%2 [L,NE,R=301]
```